# What is the lowest RNP approach requirement without being RNP AR?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach, rnav, precision-approach

I was recently told by a friend that as soon as RNP for an approach is below the 1.0/0.3nm standard that it is required to be RNP AR.

At least here in Australia, a curved segment anywhere on the approach will qualify it as RNP AR, even if the RNP is 1.0/0.3nm.

Is there a hard and fast rule for RNP AR?

Comment: I feel like this subject of RNP could use a Wiki for disambiguation.  You could ask this question in 10 different ways.  Ie "What is the difference between RNP AR and RNP 0.3?" would be one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [ICAO DOC 9905 (Required Navigation Performance Authorization Required Procedure Design Manual)](https://code7700.com/pdfs/icao/icao_doc_9905.pdf#page=17) you can find the following definition in Chapter 2.1

> ### RNP APCH versus RNP AR APCH
>
> 2.1.1 RNP APCH is defined as an RNP approach procedure that requires a lateral TSE of +/-1 NM in the initial,
>   intermediate and missed approach segments (MAS) and a lateral TSE of ±0.3 NM in the FAS. Guidance on
>   implementing RNP APCH operations can be found in the PBN Manual, Volume II, Chapter 5, Implementing RNP APCH.
>
> 2.1.2 RNP AR APCH is defined as an RNP approach procedure that requires a lateral TSE as low as ±0.1 NM
>   on any segment of the approach procedure. RNP AR APCH procedures also require that a specific vertical accuracy be
>   maintained as detailed in the PBN Manual, Volume II, Part B, Chapter 6. The datum crossing point (DCP) for RNP AR
>   procedures is the point located above the landing threshold point (LTP) or the fictitious threshold point (FTP). The RNP
>   AR APCH criteria apply only to those aircraft and operators complying with specified additional certification, approval
>   and training requirements. RNP AR APCH procedures are only published where significant operational advantages can
>   be achieved while preserving or improving safety of operation. The RNP AR certification and approval requirements are
>   contained in the PBN Manual. For the purposes of applying the criteria contained in this manual, RNP AR procedure
>   obstacle protection is associated with RNP navigation accuracy requirements. The RNP navigation accuracy
>   requirement is used to determine the area semi-width value (in NM) of a protection area associated with a segment of an
>   instrument procedure.

So, yes, any procedure below the 1.0/0.3 NM standard is defined as RNP AR.

You will not normally find curved segments (RF turns) on an RNP APCH chart, as these segments require a recent FMS as noted in ICAO DOC 8168 Vol. II Part III Appendix to Chapter 5.

> Note 5.— RF may only be used for RNP procedures flown by aircraft equipped with systems that are compatible with ARINC 424-17, or later.

In those cases the chart will be promulgated with **RF required**.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, the ICAO DOCs scare the hell out of me!

Comment: There appears to be an "RNP APCH" spec, an "RNP AR" spec, and also and "RNP 0.3" spec.  What does this RNP 0.3 spec imply then?